# Is there a word to describe someone who keeps trying to do something but always fails?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes someone who continually tries something but always fails? This isn't describing in the positive sense - as in someone who never gives up - but more about the negative side of always failing.

Examples would be someone who creates many failing businesses, someone who can never stick to a diet or someone who cannot remain faithful to their partner.

**Edit**

> More context would help narrow down the possible words that might fit
>   for this person. Why do they fail? Are they aiming too high and can't
>   attain the skillset needed to achieve success? Are they lazy? Do they
>   lack the intestinal fortitude to follow through on a goal? All of
>   these scenarios conjure different words to describe such a failure. –
>   Kristina Lopez

I'll give you an exact example to narrow it down more: A person who tries to diet and exercise but they always cave in and eat unhealthy stuff and/or skip exercise, despite knowing it'll be bad for them. Someone who's perfectly capable of doing it, has a sound mind and knowledge of why and how they should do it, but regardless, still fail each time they start doing it after a short while. I'm not talking about an unlucky person or a person who's too stupid or naive to achieve it.

However, I don't want the word to be specific to dieting (like "fatty" :P) but a word that could be used in other (albeit similar) contexts too. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: More context would help narrow down the possible words that might fit for this person.  *Why* do they fail?  Are they aiming too high and can't attain the skillset needed to achieve success?  Are they lazy?  Do they lack the intestinal fortitude to follow through on a goal?  All of these scenarios conjure different words to describe such a failure.

Comment: "Winners never quit, and quitters never win, but those who never win and never quit are idiots", as [someone once said](http://www.despair.com/stupidity.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word you are looking for is SYSYPHEAN. Although rarely used it refers to the legend of Sysyphus, a man punished by the gods by attempting to roll a rock up a hill. No matter how he tried, the rock would roll back down the hill and he would be forced to start over.
Used in a sentence it would be; Joe's many attempts at a business were sysyphean since they inevitably failed.

Comment: I like this very much!

Comment: The question asks for an adjective to be applied to a person, whereas Sisyphean is applied to a task. But since it was accepted, it must match the OP's intention, though not the literal statement of the question.

Answer (score 11):

A few suggestions:

**Loser**. Literally someone who loses, but commonly used in a derogatory sense for someone who simply can't do anything right.

**Schlemiel**. Taken from Yiddish. A hapless person, one who always makes a mess of things.

**Klutz**. Also from Yiddish, meaning a clumsy person, a person prone to accidents and mishaps, so this would be a somewhat specialized case of what you are looking for.

**Schlemazel**. Yiddish again. An unlucky person; a habitual failure.

**Bonehead**. One who is lacking in cleverness; someone who can't "get a clue."

**Failure**. The literal representation of what you are looking for. A person who always fails.

**Incompetent**. Used in the noun form; one who has no ability to accomplish something.

And from a previous generation: **Sad sack**. This was the name of a cartoon character created in World War Two, and it became a term for the kind of person you are trying to characterize. Here's the definition found in The Free Dictionary (online): An inept person who makes mistakes despite good intentions.

Comment: +1 for schlemazel - exactly the word that I thought of when reading the Q

Answer (score 9):

I think of a [***bungler***](http://www.wordnik.com/words/bungler) as a person who messes up pretty much everything he or she works on or touches.

> n. One who bungles; a clumsy, awkward workman; one who performs without skill.
>
> n. Someone who makes mistakes because of incompetence

To [*bungle*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/bungle) is defined as:

> To work or act in a clumsy, awkward, or blundering manner.
>
> To make or mend clumsily; botch; manage awkwardly or blunderingly; perform inefficiently.

Comment: I really liked the answer with all the Yiddish, but "Bungler" got my upvote.

Answer (score 8):

**Born loser**
1: a person or thing that loses especially consistently
2: a person who is incompetent or unable to succeed; also : something doomed to fail or disappoint

That's actually Merriam-Webster's definition of ["loser"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loser), which I think has an even more negative connotation. A "born" loser just naturally fails at everything, while losers probably got that way through their own poor decisions. That's strictly my take, mind you.

Answer (score 7):

**[screwup](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/screwup)** : one who hopelessly causes errors by ineptitude, carelessness, or mismanagement.

> *She's a screwup who can't hold down a job.*

Answer (score 6):

[**Weak-willed**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/weak-willed)

"lacking strength of will" describes perfectly a person who "caves in" to temptation.

Quote from OP's question:

> Someone who's perfectly capable of doing it, has a sound mind and
>   knowledge of why and how they should do it, but regardless, still fail
>   each time they start doing it after a short while

From the [free dictionary](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Chocs+away+for+children-a0208975178) I found this excerpt:

> Weak-willed, cowed parents continually cave in to "pester power,"
>   giving their spoilt kids anything they want, from junk food and sweets
>   to tellies in their bedrooms.

Answer (score 2):

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/underdog) defines **underdog** as one at a disadvantage and expected to lose; 
nonstarter, unsuccessful person, loser, failure - **a person with a record of failing; someone who loses consistently**

Comment: I think just **failure** is pretty succinct

Answer (score 1):

I like hapless.  Schlemiel also good.  Check out quixotic for a slightly different sense.  (Virtually every browser now has built in "lookup" feature", so you'll excuse me for not including definitions...not efficient to reproduce entire dictionary on SE.)

Comment: It's really helpful to include word definitions with your answer to give a little background and context for the word choices - particularly foreign words, like "Schlemiel". See @JLG's answer for an excellent example. :-)

Comment: `Shlemiel` carries the connotation of "makes his own bad luck"; `Schlemazel` is more hapless.