# Is there a word/ phrase to describe somebody who has devoted their life to practising something but is still not very good at it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms

I need a word/phrase/idiom (either adjective or noun) to describe somebody who has devoted their life to practising something but is still not very good at it.

Example:

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and still not very good at it: he is  __________ (adjective) **or** he is a _________ (noun)

Please note that the person has shown great interest and committment over a lifetime but possibly lacked the special skill or talent required to really excel at their chosen field.

Note 2: failure, misfit, disappointment, ordinary, poor and mediocre are *not* a good fit for the word I am seeking, but the case of mediocre professional musicians was the sad reality that prompted my question.

Comment: I can't see how you could say it in one word. I might incline to something like "He played the piano with less skill than resolve".

Comment: One word is not mandatory @WS2. I was looking for a descriptive phrase or idiom. 'Less skill than resolve' is a good choice and there are a few others along those lines that I am trying to remember.

Comment: DO use comments to [ask for clarification, suggest changes, or offer short-lived information](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). DO NOT use them for minor edits ([edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) instead) answers (post an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) instead), praise or rebukes ([vote](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) instead), discussion ([chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead), or comments on site design or policy (post at [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead).

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/is-there-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-keeps-trying-to-do-something-but-always

Comment: A fairly good non offensive word would be mediocre."of only average quality; not very good." He is mediocre.

Comment: I think you might be my niece (or nephew)!

Comment: "If you describe something as **mediocre**, you mean that it is **of average quality but you think it should be better**." – [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mediocre) I'd think that somebody who has devoted their life to practicing something "should be better" at it by now. *mediocre* has an underlying colloquial meaning (that definition was way down the page) that for whatever reason 'it' could or should be better, that none of its synonyms share. Admittedly, this is your word, and in my mind the title is begging for it.

Comment: Mediocre is the most basic, 'bread and butter' description @Mazura. Unfortunately this adjective does not really reflect the years of effort that went into practising that skill, I think.

Comment: Uncle remained a slogging wannabe.

Comment: *"Uncle remained a slogging wannabe."* __ certainly fits the case, @empty.

Comment: This question has been restricted so I can't enter an answer and answering in comments is condemned. As much as I am frustrated in my ability to answer I am going to frustrate the asker and the others who have answered by saying that a word with the exact meaning of "devoted their life (or at least a long time) to practising something but is still not very good at it" has existed in English for at least 500 years. If I gain rep here somehow (and I remember) I'll come back, otherwise, I hope someone else knows it.

Comment: This is exactly why Oleg from Stack Overflow wanted the SE network to allow *at least users with association bonus* to answer protected questions, and I agree @Smarty: you can see his very pertinent answer, which refers to your same problem (at another site), and my supporting comments here -- https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1694/381

Comment: A Rincewind, perhaps?

Comment: [Rincewind](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rincewind&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=zETlWc3PEerI8Ae2iYrICQ) -- thanks for introducing me to this literary reference that fits my case, @shea!

Comment: Your question just seems to perfectly fit his character!

Comment: I never heard of Rincewind before because I don't read much Science Fiction or Fantasy. We learn something new everyday! So thanks again @shea.

Comment: The word "dilettante" comes to mind. Someone who flirts with an activity or skill, but never fully commits to it.

Comment: 'Dilettante' was the first suggestion as a comment on this question and also later posted as an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/413913/231519), thanks @Dave -- but this is not *"someone who flirts with an activity or skill, but never fully commits to it"* -- the person having fully committed to the practice of the skill for years has still not become very good at it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'd suggest [Manqué](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manqu%C3%A9), a somewhat uncommon term borrowed from French.  Wikipedia describes it thus:

> Manqué (feminine, manquée) is a term used in reference to a person who has failed to live up to a specific expectation or ambition. It is usually used in combination with a profession: for example, a career civil servant with political prowess who nonetheless never attained political office might be described as a "politician manqué". It can also be used relative to a specific role model; a second-rate method actor might be referred to as a "Marlon Brando manqué".

Comment: Extremely apt if rather uncommon -- thanks for introducing me to this term @Stephen!

Answer (score 52):

**Frustrated.**

> (of a person) unable to follow or be successful in a particular career.
>   "a frustrated actor" - [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frustrated)

My father always called himself a "frustrated musician". He was a physicist and loved music, but in his opinion, his love for it exceeded his talent. Though, to be fair, he was the first person who could get a sound out of my didgeridoo the first time he held it to his lips.

Comment: Yes, a good description and rather sad too; +1 and  thanks @LindaCamillo!

Comment: I didn't mean it to be sad -- he was a humble person and was much better at music than he let on. Thank you @EnglishStudent!

Comment: you are most welcome and your suggestion much appreciated (because 'frustrated' is an apt yet unusual option) @LindaCamillo.

Comment: Note too you have included another apt expression that fits my case: "his love/ passion/ committment far exceeded his talent."

Comment: Frustrated musician/artist is also used when the subject has tried to pursue the art as a professional, but bad luck (e.g. a series of attempts to get a record contract) wore them out.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman I agree. "Frustrated" has a strong connotation of external factors or fortuitous events outside the person's control are the culprits of a less than stellar career, and the use case in the original question is more about a person doing everything in his power to pursue an interest and having not much to show for it at the end

Comment: That sounds more like a frustrat*ing*, rather than a frustrat*ed* musician ;) (no offense to your father, I'm in the same boat).

Comment: People sometimes are guided into second-choice careers their own parents considered more lucrative than their first choices. These people describe themselves as "frustrated ______s" because they actually wanted to be cartoonists, or opera singers, or something other than [[lucrative career]]. But they were discouraged from trying, not through any lack of talent.

Comment: @hlecuanda Similar to ‘thwarted’, except that it conveys a finality which ‘frustrated’ does not.

Comment: I was reading posts on History.SE and just now came across the most terrifying example of a **'frustrated artist'**: *"Adolf Hitler's goal in life was initially to become an artist. However, the Academy of Fine Arts Vienna denied Hitler's admission twice, in 1907 and 1908"* says member @ American Luke at the beginning of this answer to a question which is (warning) about war crimes:  https://history.stackexchange.com/a/2534

Answer (score 29):

This is likely to require a lookup, but it's an easy one and the meaning (and connotation!) are unambiguous: **a Florence Foster Jenkins**.

[Wikipedia has a good overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Foster_Jenkins); she was someone who wanted to be an opera singer since she was a child, rich enough that nobody was willing to tell her that she wasn't any good, and determined enough that at age 76 she rented Carnegie Hall for her only public performance. She's been described as "the world's worst opera singer".

Comment: Very interesting reference, and very appropriate as well -- after reading Wikipedia I should also admire the lady's extraordinary determination to live her dream career -- moreover, the reference seems obscure enough to the modern lay person that if used as a criticism the recipient will hopefully not understand the significance: thanks for educating me @chrylis!

Comment: @EnglishStudent FFJ's life's ambition was recently made into a movie starring Meryl Streep and Hugh Grant, so I suspect moviegoers (Americans and British)  and cinephiles will easily get the reference.

Comment: _"People may say I can't sing," she once remarked to a friend, "but no one can ever say I **didn't** sing."_ I like this woman.

Answer (score 22):

A life time practising and he's just a **flop**.

[Oxford Definition :](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flop)

> Informal (of a performer or show) be completely unsuccessful; fail totally.
>   ‘the show flopped in London’

Comment: This is the best answer. Frustrated can be mistaken for emotion, Manque and Florence Foster Jenkins are likely to mean nothing to most people, talentless has no connotation of it being a career or over time. Flop has the connotation of long-term failure in the context of a career.

Comment: But I think that competent actors/directors/writers/etc. can have random flops despite generally excelling otherwise.

Comment: Is flop ever used to indicate a person though? I've only seen it used for performances, releases and ventures. Things, not people.

Comment: @Mast The Oxford definition (above) includes the word 'performer'. I have edited to make that clearer.

Comment: Ah, not going to argue with the Oxford, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 18):

May I suggest the following,

### would-be

the term by itself will not imply that the person has struggled to achieve their heart's desire but it will suggest they are trying and they have as yet to reach that pinnacle.

> Look at Uncle, the **would-be** pianist, he's practised music all his life and he's still not very good.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would-be) defines it as

> disparaging
>   :desiring, intending, professing, or having the potential to be
>    • *a would-be actor*

*Oxford Dictionaries* say:

> Desiring or aspiring to be a specified type of person
>   • ‘So, once again, I would caution would-be writers against excessive length.’

If I wanted to emphasize the person's unsuccessful bid, I might add

### [a failed](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20failed%20would-be%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP_eyNs-jWAhVKKFAKHdM6CAo4HhD8BQgJKAA&biw=1303&bih=616&dpr=1.1) [would-be](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20failed%20would-be%22&tbm=bks&ei=S_fdWbjEBMnTwQLUw57wAg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1303&bih=616&dpr=1.1)

There aren't as many hits on either Google or Google Books, but that is to be expected, it is not a complimentary term, and it is slightly unwieldy.

Comment: 'Would be' is quite good enough in context, and 'failed' makes it final, thanks @Mari-lou A -- now you have suggested another good possibility within a definition you quoted: *'aspiring'* is ironic indeed when the person has been aspiring for 2 decades! 2 other expressions that come to mind (usually used in sports context) are ['lacklustre performance'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=lacklustre+performance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KhHeWZmJM-WK8QfFo634Bg) and ["yet to get out of first gear."](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22get+out+of+first+gear%22+idiom)

Comment: @EnglishStudent *‘aspiring’* is a great word, it is closely connected to *‘inspire’*, and to *‘respire’*, which also means: • *recover hope, courage, or strength after a time of difficulty.* However, it lacks that essential "dashed hopes/dreams" aspect that your question demands.

Comment: Yes indeed @Mari-lou A -- 'aspiring' is more ironic than a proper description of the situation. One of the best suggestions here was the one by 1006a (perennial journeyman) -- I also heard somewhere ['always an apprentice.'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22always+an+apprentice%22&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&oq=%22always+an+apprentice%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3..0i8i30.4690.7073.0.7491.2.2.0.0.0.0.262.513.2-2.2.0....0...1.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..0.2.512.fcT865lMbLo)

Answer (score 17):

It might be best not to overthink it.  A *talent* is a person's natural aptitude or ability for something, so someone who lacks this ability is ***talentless***.

Comment: *"It might be best not to overthink it"* __ thanks for reminding; so 'talentless' or 'lacks talent' is absolutely right on target @AffableAmbler! I upvotes. That puts me in mind of this rather commonly heard expression: https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-really-mean-when-someone-says-theyre-not-cut-out-for-something

Comment: Or "ungifted" / "lacked the gift", etc

Comment: talentless is quite strong - ungifted may be more friendly.  Many people do things who are ungifted, adequate for common use (playing at open-mic night, local club, etc) though they are not talentless.  
A sports player to makes it through college on a scholarship may be talented, yet ungifted and never make it to the pros.

Answer (score 15):

How about this?

"He is still an **amateur**, and all his hard work and practice have **come to naught**."

Or

“He is an **amateur**, and despite all his practice, his skills are still **bush league**.”

Comment: "despite all his practice, still an amateur" is very appropriate to my situation; thanks @Headblender.

Comment: 'Amateur' is a tricky word.  The early scientists were 'amateurs', they had the leisure and resources to pursue pure science rather than being forced to make a living by getting their hands dirty with engineering!   And for a long time amateur sportsmen were considered superior, morally and even sometimes in practice - the 'Gentlemen' often beat the 'Players' at cricket.  Maybe make your attitude to 'amateur' clear.  'Despite years of work, he remained irredeemably amateur.'

Comment: Amateur has 2 relevant meanings **(A)** Someone who pursues a study or sport as a pastime [ might be he is very good at it , but it is not his profession ] & **(B)** Someone who is unqualified or not skillful enough [ the meaning required by @EnglishStudent ] ; but there is another word which has only the second negative meaning : **amateurish**. My suggestion : **"Despite all his practice, he is still amateurish."**

Comment: Very pertinent point @Laurence Payne!

Comment: You are right: 'amateurish' is the most appropriate form of the word for my situation @Prem.

Comment: @EnglishStudent , I will convert my comment into an answer. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413534/is-there-a-word-phrase-to-describe-somebody-who-has-devoted-their-life-to-pract/413784#413784

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps [***perennial also-ran***](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&tbm=bks&q=%22perennial%20also-ran%22&oq=%22perennial%20also-ran%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...341288.345279.0.346188.4.4.0.0.0.0.546.937.0j3j5-1.4.0....0...1.1j4.64.psy-ab..0.1.167...0.0.kd4Mx60n6IQ) would work for you. Per Oxford Dictionaries, an [*also-ran*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/also-ran) can be

> 1.1. *informal* An undistinguished or unsuccessful person or thing.

The term often collocates with [*perennial*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/perennial), meaning

> 1. Lasting or existing for a long or apparently infinite time; enduring or continually recurring.
>      . . .
>      1.2. *attributive* (of a person) apparently permanently engaged in a specified role or way of life.

As a whole, the phrase suggests someone who keeps training and showing up for the competition, but who never wins (or even places or shows).

So in your example:

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and still not very good at it: he is a **perennial also-ran**.

If that expression sounds too harsh, a similar expression with more suggestion of success (just not total mastery) is [*perennial **journeyman***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22perennial%20journeyman%22). A [*journeyman*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/journeyman) is

> A worker or sports player who is reliable but not outstanding.

Traditionally, of course, a journeyman was a Craftsman who had served out an apprenticeship and was still honing hours or her skill on the way towards becoming a matter of the craft. So the term already implies years of hard work on a skill; modifying it with *perennial* (or perhaps something like *perpetual*) will give the clear implication that "matter" status is permanently out of reach.

This this phrase would work well if Uncle is a good enough musician to play at parties, but not brilliant enough for the concert hall or a record deal. Or if he's still pretty bad, but you want to be as kind as possible. Note, however, that this is a much rarer phrase than *perennial also-ran*, which is common enough that I would almost call it a fixed phrase.

Comment: I don't think "also-ran" is quite right here, but **journeyman** fits the requirements well I think.,

Comment: Both 'also-ran' (but never won) and 'journeyman' are extremely appropriate here and the meaning is further clarified by 'perennial' -- genuinely good suggestions for the particular situation, +1 and thanks @1006a!

Answer (score 13):

You might consider this noun phrase, or something like it:

**Perpetual novice**

This phrase is sometimes used in the field of software development
(and possibly elsewhere) 
to refer to someone who has acquired plenty of experience without acquiring
the high level of skill that is expected to come with the experience.
An example of this usage is in the title of the blog post
["perpetual novice – years of experience vs skill"](https://www.selikoff.net/2009/04/12/perpetual-novice-years-of-experience-vs-skill/).

*Novice* (or a word with similar meaning such as *beginner,* *neophyte,*
or *apprentice*) implies someone who is trying to learn something in
which they are not yet expert.
Like most of its synonyms, *novice* also implies that someone is
new to this field of endeavor,
so the word *perpetual* makes the phrase an oxymoron.
The perpetual novice may put in many years of earnest effort
but will never become an expert.

Comment: Thanks for a very accurate expression @David K -- something similar I was thinking of is ['always an apprentice.'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22always+an+apprentice%22&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&oq=%22always+an+apprentice%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3..0i8i30.4690.7073.0.7491.2.2.0.0.0.0.262.513.2-2.2.0....0...1.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..0.2.512.fcT865lMbLo)

Answer (score 11):

***Enthusiastic amateur***:  **amateur**, as defined by [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Amature) is:

> lacking professional skill or expertise.  "a very amateurish job"; "inexpert
>   but conscientious efforts"; "an unskilled painting

However, the amateur is enthusiastic, committed to practicing long hours, taking many lessons, learning difficult compositions and displaying her talents in recitals. Her art is her life.  Think of [Florence  Foster Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Foster_Jenkins_(film)) as played by Meryl Streep. the Enthusiastic Amateur believes in herself, even if no one else does.

Comment: Thanks for a really good description -- the use of 'amateur' is somewhat ironic (if technically justified) when somebody has actually trained to be a professional in the chosen field, whether music, medicine or acting but remains mediocre despite effort -- 'enthusiastic' gives it a nice qualification @ab2.

Answer (score 9):

Many answers here are pretty good, also many of them are *uncorteous* in the least of cases and plain insulting, if not offensive in the worst.

Having read on the original question that the phrase would be used to offer advise or criticism to a relative, and all things being equal, you may wish to be or stay on good terms with them, a milder but no less precise word is required, and I suggest :

---

### un·ac·com·plished

ˌənəˈkämpliSHt/
adjective.

1. showing little skill.
2. Not carried out.

*Merriam Webster* further adds: " **lacking talent, poise, grace, or achievement**"

---

Which seems befitting, since having practiced for a lifetime and being a person who probably wasn't negligent in his professional development and education, this word conveys the lack of something that would make him recognizable or memorable above the ordinary and everyday, but implying that whatever is missing is not his own fault or has yet to come, in order to be accomplished.

Using your example:

> Look at Uncle. Practised music all his life and still not very good at
>   it: he is **an unaccomplished musician** still.

Let's never forget that language is a tool for connecting with people, and people have feelings, specially about their livelihood and career choices. Advise will be more readily accepted and even appreciated if it is delivered with kind words.

Imagine someone offering you advice in the form:

> Hello `[someone's_name_here]` Look at you, all your life
>   practicing   `[occupation]` and you are, to be honest, still not
>   very good at it! You are an `[unkind_suggestion]`, and I think you
>   should `[your_best_advise]`.

Try substituting `[unkind_suggestion]` with some of the accurate, witty and patently correct answers in this thread.

Most likely, your party will stop listening before "... and I think you should....." failing the whole purpose of communicating with someone else, even if your advise was good, pertinent, clear, pragmatic, useful, realistic and profitable.

You would have just wasted your time, lost karma and brownie points with those who disagree with you and probably this person's friendship. Not a good deal in the least.,

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a very neutral term @hlecuanda! 'Unaccomplished' really fits the case in question. May I also clarify that this is not meant to talk about an actual person (and I have no relative who is a musician) but meant to refer to the generic case of people who devote their life to learning something (medicine/ law/ music/ politics) but they are still not very good at it. Music was just the example thst motivated my question, and your answer is very much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure! I was a bit unsettled because many of the answers, although precise and correct, completely disregard the idea that language is used mainly to communicate with other people. With the exception of technical fields, where being correct, precise and unambiguous is paramount, we should take care which words we choose to communicate, so as to not sow discord, resentment or hurtfulness. There are plenty of people in positions of power already taking care of that, so why join their destructive efforts? The proverbial Grandma's advise applies here: "If you can't say something nice...." =)

Comment: Very true @hlecuanda. I know a teacher who used to say, *speak nice or be silent.* Communication is the primary purpose of language. A secondary purpose is definition and clarification of concepts. In this particular case, the purpose wasn't communication and especially not criticism of real persons, but that I was seeking a word or phrase which clarifies my own internal concept of a person who devoted his life to something and is still not good enough -- how he will feel and how others will think of him -- for which your suggestion 'unaccomplished' is a neutral description that fits the case.

Comment: I think "stubbornly unaccomplished" adds a little bit of cheek to your excellent answer

Answer (score 8):

To me, this seems like **a hack**

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hack

> hack
>
> noun
>   1. a person, as an artist or writer, who exploits, for money, his or her creative ability or training in the production of dull,
>   unimaginative, and trite work; one who produces banal and mediocre
>   work in the hope of gaining commercial success in the arts: As a
>   painter, he was little more than a hack.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, @Scott Seidman -- 'hack' is really close to my meaning of 'somewhat competent, not highly skilled, not very creative.'

Comment: Be careful with this one to ensure the subject is unambiguous, as a "hack" can also refer to a particularly clever (albeit temporary) solution to a problem. As long as it's directed at a person, this answer is spot on. #EnglishIsWeird

Answer (score 7):

### Many Adjectives Might Do

You may want to make a qualifying statement in your context to best convey this (the italicized portion). Then the word **[inept](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inept)** would work:

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life, yet **inept** *at the finer points*.

Or more drastic:

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life, yet **inept** *at the basics*.

The qualification is needed because the definition is very direct:

> Having or showing no skill; clumsy.

So you need to qualify that he has been unable to obtain the "finer" aspects of the skill (or even worse, the "basics") that would be evident in a proficiency or mastery of it.

However, there still exists words that can convey the idea of not having mastery without the qualification. Some dictionaries note the word **[unproficient](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unproficient)** (Oxford) exists, along with **[inexpert](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inexpert)** (also recognized by [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inexpert), unlike the former term as of this posting) which are adjectives that indicate *not* gaining a level of proficiency or expertise, while still grasping the basics (as one who studied lifelong would possess).

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and still **unproficient**.
>
> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and still **inexpert**.

In a similar way, a variety of words can covey the inexpertise by referencing the commonality: [**average**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/average), [**commonplace**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commonplace), [**middle-of-the-road**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/middle-of-the-road). The last one even states:

> (of music) tuneful but somewhat bland and unadventurous

So

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and still **middle-of-the-road**.

And then some adjectives that really have connotations of inferiority: **[second-rate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/second-rate)**, **[run-of-the-mill](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/run-of-the-mill)**, **[tolerable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tolerable)**.

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and still only **tolerable**.

### The Noun is the More Challenging

To convey the "life" concept, then maybe **[lifer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lifer)**, which has as part of the definition (Oxford):

> *North American* A person who spends their life in a particular career, especially in one of the armed forces.

Or [Webster's more generic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lifer):

> a person who has made a lifelong commitment (as to a way of life)

So you could reduce the sentence to:

> Look at Uncle, musically he is just a **second-rate lifer**.

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive answer that addresses noun and adjective separately -- I especially like 'second-rate' and 'run of the mill' @ScottS.

Answer (score 6):

After all that time he's a **nonperformer**.

> A person who or thing which does not perform well or as required; a person who does not live up to expectation.

[Nonperformer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/non-performer)

One of the definitions of the noun indicates a longterm aspect, the failure to adhere to a contract, so not momentary.

[Nonperformance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonperformance)

Comment: Does that imply inability or a momentary failure?

Comment: Good suggestion, +1 @Nigel! Are you sure it's not momentary as mentioned by Josh in the first comment?

Comment: @EnglishStudent Edited to show it has longterm aspect

Comment: Thanks @Nigel -- you may like to look at this definition which comes directly to the performing arts and 'below expectations' aspects: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/non-performer

Comment: Thanks @EnglishStudent I had it there already but I messed up the link. OK now.

Answer (score 5):

He is still a **nonstarter**

> A person or plan that has no chance of succeeding or being effective.

[Nonstarter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/non-starter)

Comment: Nonstarter was in my thoughts after your own answer of 'nonperformer' -- it fits, thanks again @Nigel J!

Comment: @EnglishStudent I'm sure there's more to come. Give it time.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to rewrite your sentence just a little bit more, you could write

> ... he **gets an A for effort.**

From the [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs (via The Free Dictionary)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+for+effort)
we have the definition

> A for effort
>
> Fig. acknowledgement for having tried to do something, even if it was not successful.

In my experience, this usually implies the result was *not* successful;
this meaning is reflected in the definition in
[The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=A%20for%20effort).

The phrase above (with the letter "A") works well when used with an audience in the United States, since in many schools in the U.S. "high marks" is an A.
If you're writing for people in countries that do not use the letter-grade system (A, B, C, etc.) to measure students' performance in school,
you might write

> ... he **gets high marks for effort.**

People sometimes give an "E for effort," which means high marks to some people (who went to schools where "E" was awarded for *excellent* performance) but not to others.

Comment: "High marks for effort" is a good expression, thanks @David K!

Answer (score 5):

In John le Carre's novel 'A Perfect Spy' the term 'nevver-wozza' is frequently used (the spelling may be a bit off, sorry, but a more correct spelling would be 'never-was-a'). IMO this is a lovely bit of slang.

It's a play on 'has-been', which is someone who was good at something in the past but is now unable to move on from those glory days. On the other hand a 'nevver'wozza' was never very good at anything no matter how much they tried or how fundamental the task was to their existence (in the novel it is often used to describe race horses).

Comment: *"a 'nevver'wozza' was never very good at anything no matter how much they tried or how fundamental the task was to their existence"* __ totally accurate definition for the situation, thanks @MattH!

Answer (score 5):

Never was.

Similar but a non-distorted version of the answer by @MattH.  Someone who hasn't achieved anything in the course of their career as suggested in the quote by [C. Northcote Parkinson](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/c/cnorthcot378084.html) ~

> It is better to be a 'has-been' than a 'never-was'

Comment: The quote makes 'never-was' a good option, thanks @mcalex. I suppose it is to be used as a noun, but a verb form is also possible as in 'top grade artist? He never was.'

Answer (score 4):

Within the context of orchestral music (and other organisations) we have "[rank-and-file](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rank-and-file)", which is someone who is *ok* - they can play the parts, but they lack the passion or talent to excel.  It's the alternative to "[virtuoso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuoso)", in the musical world.

There's an Italian (I think) word for a rank and file musician, which I can't put my finger on at the moment, which might work well....

Comment: Thank you. 'Rank and file' is the type of near-technical term that expresses my meaning neutrally @Max Williams.

Comment: There is an idiom in Spanish "ser del montón" Which translates neatly to "just someone else in the crowd" as the virtuosso stands out for his unique abilities, the "crowd" makes individuals  indistinguishable, i.e. nothing special about them.

Answer (score 4):

> [dilettante](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilettante)

is a pretty good word for this, except that it implies a lack of serious commitment.

However, I would venture that someone who has devoted their lives to a practice would at least be able to perform at a serviceable level, even without much aptitude.  If that's not the case it's likely the person wasn't really as committed as they made themselves out to be in terms of practice
.

Comment: This word was the first suggestion to this question, in a comment by a senior member, and it is close in meaning, thanks @aDukeZhou -- except for the 'implies a lack of serious commitment' as you yourself pointed out. However serious committment is not lacking here.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I'd tend to favor "inept" in that case.  *(More genteel than simply telling them they "suck";)*

Comment: Inept is an accurate description @DukeZhou.

Answer (score 3):

While **"amateur"** has 2 relevant meanings :
**(1)** [Someone who pursues a study or sport as a pastime](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/amateur) [[ might be , he is very good at it , but it is not his profession ]] ,
**(2)** Someone who is unqualified or not skillful enough [[ **the connotation or meaning required by @EnglishStudent** ]] ,
there is another word which has only the second negative meaning : **"amateurish"**.

My suggestion : **"Despite all his practice, he is still amateurish."**

[[ I wanted to mention that this was originally my comment to an answer by @headblender , but since I got a response from OP , I decided to add it as answer ]]

[[ Also wanted to mention that @laurence-payne had also commented about the trickiness of using "amateur" ]]

Comment: 'Amateurish' is a solid description, thanks for writing as an answer @Prem. The fine distinction you made between 'amateur' and 'amateurish' is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Although the dictionary definitions don't really express your meaning directly, I would still be inclined to call him a ***[piker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piker)***:

> 2 :one who does things in a small way
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piker)*</sub>

This is a negative word, with the implication in your case that they never took risks (even while practicing), or really engaged in serious self-analysis, to really improve; they just went along doing more or less what they had always done to get by.

An example usage:

> The other morning I told my husband that when it came to snoring, compared to him I was a piker.
>   <sub>*from [WorldWideWords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pik1.htm)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to a new word @Hellion! It's a fact that some musicians never really stretched themselves and therefore fell short, but there have been many others in various fields who actually lacked the talent to match their commitment.

Comment: That's interesting. As an Australian, I've always known "piker" to mean  1.  someone who opts out of an arrangement or challenge or does not do their fair share.

2.  someone who gambles, speculates, etc., in a small, cautious way: *I wasn't a piker either. I knew my horses. I had my daydreams. Today might be the day I'd back the programme. –SUTTON WOODFIELD, 1960.

3.  someone who, from diffidence or lack of courage, does anything in a contemptibly small or cheap way.


From the "Macquarie Dictionary Online"

Comment: Your definitions 2 and 3 exactly fit Hellion's meaning @Livrecache.

Comment: Ah, yes @EnglishStudent, but most Australians would only be familiar with the first definition. We (and the New Zealanders) seem to have come up with our own meaning of 'piker'.

Answer (score 2):

After pursuing something over my lifetime, to be unrewarded by even modest levels of accomplishment is to suffer an ***unrequited*** devotion.

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and still not very good at it: he is ***unrequited***.

unrequited
adjective
 (of a feeling, especially love) not returned or rewarded.

Comment: Your unusual use of 'unrequited' is appropriate here, thanks @Stan -- would 'unrewarded' or 'didn't get his reward' work as well?

Comment: @EnglishStudent I considered the pursuit to be a labour of love. How else to describe such tenacity? No physical reward can be worth a lifetime of focussed, unpretentious effort. No degree of excellence in the opinion of an observer need justify the worth of a lifetime devoted to the pursuit of pleasure.

Comment: Very true; @Stan -- moreover, many such a person (including humble myself in certain amateur pursuits related to history, literature, and the sound of music from the 'listener's end') has actually felt quite satisfied with their achievements, which is all that really matters, even when external objective assessments might possibly say 'not really good enough!'

Answer (score 2):

He is a man with a bright future behind him

Comment: 'Bright future behind him' __ too true, thanks @Neil_UK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the goal is to shame him in his failure or to politely describe his lack of positive results for his efforts.

This might do;
Look at Uncle Kyle, he's practiced music all his life and remains a beginner.

Comment: It's not a specific case. I am looking for a term to describe the sad generic irony/paradox of someone practising something with full dedication all their life and not being much good at it anyway. *"...and remains a beginner"* is *very* apt, thanks @user2863749.

Comment: Then an "Eternal beginner" might do. Or a "Perennial beginner".

Answer (score 1):

If one desires to be more on the positive of things, it might be a good idea to employ the following expression:

> Look at Uncle, practised music all his life and is still not very good at it, yet he is a such a **tenacious trier**.

[Tenacious](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tenacious) gives the meaning of strong-willed, resolute and persistent.

A for the word [trier](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trier), it gives us the following sense of positivity:

> If you say that someone is a trier, you approve of them because they try very hard at things that they do, although they are not often successful.
>
> *He may not always achieve greatness but at least he's a trier*.

Comment: Thanks for a much better way of putting it, @Ken Graham! 3 other related expressions I was thinking of were 'nobody can fault his committment', 'he always gives 100%' and 'he never gives up' where *'he may not be the most skilled person'* is left unstated, but rather implied in context.

Answer (score -3):

Simpleton or Underachiever or castaway or lost one or clueless or try-hard or feeble-minded.

Personally I would go with **clueless** cause it makes more sense when addressing a particular case

Comment: Thanks @user261343 -- I have actually considered 'underachiever' an accurate description for many such persons. 'Clueless' should also work if they are *really* weak at their craft, I think.

Comment: I have never heard "clueless" being used in this context. _Underacheiver_ is good, but I disagree with the other two.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that "underachiever" fits. According to M-W online, the definition of underachiever is

"one (such as a student) that fails to attain a predicted level of achievement or does not do as well as expected"