# Word for a person who fumbles through life

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a word that would describe someone who despite giving their best efforts, they always barely get by. Someone who tries hard but has to put in their best effort just to meet standards at their job. They manage to get the work done by the skin of their teeth when others find the same job to be easy.

This person doesn't fail, they SOMEHOW manage to meet standards. But every day is like, "All that work for a C-"

I've considered mediocre, but that seems like it describes the person's results more than it does the person.

The phrase, "coasting through life" comes to mind, but that to me implies lack of effort.

The phrase "hanging by a thread" comes to mind, as this person often feels like that is what they are always doing.

The closest thing I can think of is "fumbley" (if that was a word.) As this person is often set back by mistakes, clumsiness or in some cases just not able to think and act as fast as their peers, yet they can manage to get the work done as long as they work harder than everyone else.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/is-there-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-keeps-trying-to-do-something-but-always. Have a look at this possible duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word to describe someone who keeps trying to do something but always fails?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/is-there-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-keeps-trying-to-do-something-but-always)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I edited my original post to clarify how my question is different.

Comment: A “low performer”might fit this type of person

Comment: Low performer is in the right direction, but to me that feels more like an attitude thing, or someone who would make an unsatisfactory grade. I guess they would be the lowest performer in the particular group. In a group of all A+ workers they probably receive a B, but a B just seems so low in contrast.

Comment: When you say *fumble*, I think you mean *bumble*.  And the person who does that would be a bumbler.  Could you check a dictionary and see if that fits?

Comment: Bumble and Stumble both fit part of my question. But it doesn't feel like it describes a person who is working hard and meeting standards despite the stumbling.

Comment: Check out blunder also.

Comment: Blunder is also in the right direction. I'm looking for a word for "a person who manages to meet standards despite blundering." By putting in more effort than others do.

Comment: @kiseochan I think you might be confusing 'low performer' with 'underachiever'. An underachiever is someone who fails to perform as well as they could, this is often down to attitude. For instance I have seen professional soccer players described (unfairly) as "academic underachievers" because many of them will have concentrated on football at the expense of academic study. A "low performer" I would see as being someone of lower inherent ability.

Comment: I had a friend who described herself as a "plodder" in contrast to a sister to whom everything seemed to come easily.