# Word for someone who wants to do good but consistently fails

Tags: single-word-requests

The word would be an antonym for someone who is efficient, reliable, and whose actions produce consistently positive results.

In other words, a bumbling, well-intentioned person - but I'm looking for a single word adjective.

Comment: Also see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/is-there-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-keeps-trying-to-do-something-but-always  .... Or  maybe **hapless**?

Comment: Sounds like an incapable to me.

Comment: First, what is the single-word adjective for someone who is efficient, reliable, and whose actions produce consistently positive results?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - *hapless* sounds good to me " Esp. of a person: destitute of or lacking good fortune; unfortunate, unlucky. Hence also in later use: incompetent, clumsy. "(OED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bungler**

Someone who is likely to screw up anything and everything

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bungler

Comment: And the adjective would be "bungling"

Answer (score 0):

### Ineffectual

According to the Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

(https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ineffectual)

> without the ability to achieve much; weak; not achieving what you want to

> "He plays the role of a blustering and ineffectual teacher"